# Strange output in Ruby Longest Palindrome substring function

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, nested, palindrome

I am trying to develop a function which will return the longest palindrome substring of an entered string. I am right now working on breaking up the string so that each subsection could then be analyzed to see if it is a palindromeThe code is as follows:

```
def longest_palindrome(s)
  place = 0
  array = s.chars
  output = []
  while place < s.length
    output << (array[0]..array[place]).to_a
    place += 1
  end
  return output
end
```

if given string "ababa" I would expect the resulting array to look like this:

```
[["a"],["a","b"],["a","b","a"],["a","b","a","b"],["a","b","a","b","a"]]
```

However, when i return the output array this is what is stored inside:

```
[["a"], ["a", "b"], ["a"], ["a", "b"], ["a"], ["a", "b"]]
```

What about my function is causing this to happen?

Edit:

Not sure if I should start another topic for this. My code is now as follows:

```
def longest_palindrome(s)
 array = s.chars
 start = 0
 place = 1
 output = []
 while start < s.length - 1
    while place < s.length
      output << array[start..place]
      place += 1
    end
 start += 1
 end
return output  
end
```

My logic is that this will start at index 0, then progressively capture one character more of the string until the whole string is complete. Then it will start on index 1 and do the same until it has gotten all possible substrings within the string. However, it only returns:

```
[["a"],["a","b"],["a","b","a"],["a","b","a","b"],["a","b","a","b","a"]]
```

Where is the flaw in my logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misusing the range operator to produce ranges like `'a'..'a'`, which is just `'a'`.

You have two completely independent array indexing operations, each of which return a single element (character) from the array to be used in a range. You're getting `array[0]`, which is always `a`, and `array[place]` which alternates between `a` and `b`, and producing the ranges `'a'..'a'` and `'a'..'b'` over and over, which have nothing to do with the arrays the characters originally came from.

You can't build the ranges *after* extracting the elements from the array and expect the ranges to be produced *from* the array. The correct sub-array is produced by using the range as the index of the array: `array[0..place]`. This returns the sub-array from `0` to `place`, inclusive.

Comment: Thanks! makes perfect sense.